# Ionic Framework - Open sqlite database within device

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been using cordova sqlite successfully when I have a db file inside the www folder. The problem is that now I have to download a db and unzip it within the device's documents.

that's my code so far (to get the database within www):

```
var app = angular.module('foobar');

app.factory('factoryDatabase', function($cordovaDialogs, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicLoading, $q, serviceConstants){

    // my current db....
    var currentDB = undefined;
    var DATABASE_NAME = 'Data.db';
    var PATH = 'Data.db';

    return{
        init: function(){
            if (currentDB == undefined) {
                currentDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                    name: DATABASE_NAME,
                    createFromResource: PATH
                });

            }
            return currentDB;
        },

    }
});
```

The main problem is the PATH constant, it's pointing to www folder (by default) and the project (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) doesn't seem to support changing the path to the device's files for both android and iOS

anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This comment is a side track so pls dont mark down but maybe you want to try PouchDB pouchdb.com this is a great tool that lets you inerface with SQLite without doing much. I have found it to have defensive code for some SQLite problems.

Comment: @SaniYusuf Thanks for the help, I'll check it out.